# WCF Windows Service not releasing resources/memory after every call

Tags: windows-services, memory-leaks, wcf, memory-management

I have created WCF application which is running on Windows Service. It was installed using Windows Installer. I have followed procedure mentioned in following article for same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic4

Most WCF properties are kept as default for net.tcp protocol, per call instance and so on.

Memory consumption of service keeps on increasing after every call and does not decrease. At the end it throws OutOfMemory consumption.

Application returns very heavy string based data. With memory-profiler I found memory is still allocated to string objects and increases during call.

As per my understanding string is managed objects should release data once out of scope.

Let me know if any other configuration/coding information is needed specifically.

Comment: Strings, like anything else, will only be released when nothing has a reference to them anymore. If you see strings not being released, that's a symptom, not the problem. Figure out which object would be holding on to an instance of that string, and then figure out who's still holding on to a reference to that object. Or ignore the strings in your profiler, and look at which of *your* classes are getting leaked.

Comment: I have checked my code in perf mon for large objects LOH msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx and found that they are present. Searching net I could not find any suitable way to handle LOH behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many unsuccessful attempts to handle LOH (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx) which was very large string in my context, I have created custom class to handle it.

Instead of storing large string in single object am storing it as collection of small strings in custom object. .NET disposed it properly without creating above mentioned problem.

Other possible solution with worked for me is to use file object to store large file and access it as text reader. This works well and keeps footprint of application small. Unfortunately for me it did not work and accessing file location was not allowed for application.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something keeping references to those strings in the code. Can you use your profiler to trace the references that are keeping the string objects alive?

Comment: Using memory pro-filer I found many objects are still in memory and not getting released. Even string object is not released, though I think it might be related to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx this. Am arriving at conclusion that I need to restart service if it reaches certain memory limit.

Comment: Can't you publish what kind of objects are not released? Are there any disposable objects that you are not disposing probably?

Comment: Kindly check newly added comment.

Comment: When a collection occurs, those objects (including the strings) will be unallocated UNLESS there is a specific traceable connection to a root object. Do a trace for one of these string objects that should be getting release to reveal the reference path that is keeping the object alive. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to answer this question without some code to look at.  You can always call GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration) to force garbage collection and see if this doesn't reduce your memory consumption.  Ideally this would only be temporary code to track down what is going on in the application.  If forcing garbage collection does not reduce memory consumption then references to the strings must be being retained, via static member variables or whatever: having no conception of what the code is, any theory would be a shot in the dark

Comment: I did tried GC.Collect() and some other garbage collector methods but it ended up with no result. Apparently I found it is related to large objcts LOH http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx, which does not get disposed properly.

Comment: kindly check newly added comment.